# Config.json inArguments Data Binding with Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, configuration, app, activity

I'm struggling to configure my app with Marketing Cloud, after define my JB (setting Entry Event and Data Extension properly) my inArguments isn't binding with the event (I'm using Jmeter to execute the tests) I really don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
"arguments": {
    "execute": {
        "inArguments":[
            { "firstName":"{{Interaction.5f854a37-40cd-4dc6-81cf-f55c4bb89d98.CPF}}"}
        ],
        "outArguments": [
            { "teste":"number" }
        ],
```

Also I tried other ways, like replacing `Interaction` to `Event` and using different Event API keys, inside my journey builder when I click inside the event I'have this one : APIEvent-649122ef-96c4-c22e-815f-eb9b508b7fec

Also inside my app I have this following code to get this inArgument

```
var aArgs = req.body.inArguments;
console.log('[aArgs]:'+aArgs);
console.log('[aArgs]:'+req.body);
var oArgs = {};
for (var i=0; i<aArgs.length; i++) {
  for (var key in aArgs[i]) {
    oArgs[key] = aArgs[i][key];
    console.log('[key]:'+key+';oArgs[key]:'+oArgs[key]);
  }
}
```

My log is showing :

```
2017-04-20T02:22:13.889030+00:00 app[web.1]: [aArgs]:[object Object]
2017-04-20T02:22:13.888985+00:00 app[web.1]: [aArgs]:[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
2017-04-20T02:22:13.889062+00:00 app[web.1]: [key]:firstName;oArgs[key]:
2017-04-20T02:22:13.889103+00:00 app[web.1]: [key]:priority;oArgs[key]:4
2017-04-20T02:22:13.889129+00:00 app[web.1]: [key]:priority;oArgs[key]:4
2017-04-20T02:22:13.889162+00:00 app[web.1]: [key]:priority;oArgs[key]:4
2017-04-20T02:22:13.889206+00:00 app[web.1]: [key]:priority;oArgs[key]:4
2017-04-20T02:22:13.889237+00:00 app[web.1]: [fname]:
```

Also inside my Data Extension model I have the CPF field

Can you guys please help me ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using data binding in the Interaction context, specifically, the binding you are getting the `CPF` value of outArgument from a prior Custom Activity with the key `5f854a37-40cd-4dc6-81cf-f55c4bb89d98` which I'm pretty sure is not what you want. (*side note: you can only retrieve OutArguments from prior Custom Activities, not standard Activities*).

If you have a field named `CPF` in your Event Source Data Extension and you want to use this as an inArgument, then your data binding should look like this:

```
{{Event.eventDefinitionKey.CPF}}
```

Where `eventDefinitionKey` is the Event Definition Key value for the Event.

Comment: Also I was missing the association between Data Extension with Contact inside Audience Builder, thank you a lot Eliot !

Comment: Eliot, one more thing, is it possible to bind the outArgument inside the Data Extension in the same way ? For instance ` "outArguments": [
             { "email":"text" }` or `{{Event.eventDefinitionKey.EMAIL}}` ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The outArgument passes a value from your Custom Activity to preceding Custom Activities in your Journey. Can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Is it possible to use this outArgument to update the Data Extension ?

Comment: It might be, but then again it might not. If you add an Update Contact Data Activity to your Journey after the custom activity then paste in the data binding string with the value `{{Interaction.insertYourCustomActivityKeyHere.number}}` (where `number` is the value from your outArgument) this might work. Data binding is supported in Update Contact Data Activities, but I have only been able to get outArguments passed as inArguments to subsequent Custom Activities, not Standard Activities. Let me know how you go.

Comment: Of course, another solution would be to use the Marketing Cloud API to update a Data Extension of your choice from within your Custom Activity...

Comment: It's a nice idea, for while I'm trying to set the update Activity with my App Key registered inside App Center but I'm receiving a message that this key does not exists, very strange.

Comment: The key is the value that is assigned to this Custom Activity when creating the Journey. This will almost certainly be `REST-1` but you can validate this by retrieving the Journey using the [getInteractionById method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/getInteractionById.htm).

Comment: Eliot, I had to use the REST API integration to perform the update, I hadn't success using update contact activity,

Comment: That's what I suspected; it appears that outArguments in Custom Activities can only be consumed by other Custom Activities, not Standard Activities.